# React mocha/enzyme Imported function test failed during render

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, sinon, chai, enzyme

i want to test if my component renders properly. This is my test:

```
describe('Send Action', () => {
  it ('Should render without errors', () => {
    const props = {
      action: Map({possibleRecipients: false}),
      context: List()
    };

    const wrapper = shallow(<Send {...props}/>);
    expect(wrapper.length).to.equal(1);
  });
});
```

Problem is that i have this line in my component that i'm testing

```
const createSelector = require("createSelector");
```

And this function is called at some point in render method of the component i'm testing. I'm getting this error even if i don't enter the expect part.

```
 TypeError: firstArgument.map is not a function inside createSelector.jsx
```

Why is it going inside that createSelector, that's another file and i don't want to test it, just my Send Action component. Do i need to stub/mock here? And if i do, how do i implement it? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use mock libraries for this. To name a few proxyquire, rewire, etc. There are excellent articles available you can search for them.